# jQuery selector issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer

The following works perfectly with any browser EXCEPT any flavour of Internet Explorer, any thoughts? It simply fails to execute! Has anyone come across this kind of problem before?

```
if ($('select[id$="<%= this.ApplicantID %>_employmentStatusList"]').val() != 'N') {
    $('[id^=mainContent_incomeDetails_1]').each(function (index) {
        var fieldvalue = $('input[id$=' + this.id + ']').val();
        if (fieldvalue != "") {
            totalincome += parseInt(fieldvalue);
        }
    });

    if (totalincome == 0) {
        $('#incomeError').dialog('open');
        validEmployment = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working??

Comment: It simply will not iterate over the div id's, just silently fails, works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari....

Comment: If you open the developers toolkit (press F12), do any errors show up in the console? It's most likely a compatibility issue with your CSS selectors in IE. Maybe use `$('*[id^=mainContent_incomeDetails_1]').each(function (index) {` and make sure you declare doctype http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Comment: No, nothing, its so odd

Comment: Where is this script situated in the document?

Comment: Have a look at my edited comment above. Likely a CSS selector issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move out <%= this.ApplicantID %> nugget, maybe ie don't get it:

```
    var appId = "<%= this.ApplicantID %>";

    if ($("select[id$=" + appId + "_employmentStatusList"]').val() != 'N') {
        $('[id^=mainContent_incomeDetails_1]').each(function (index) {
            var fieldvalue = $('input[id$=' + this.id + ']').val();
            if (fieldvalue != "") {
                totalincome += parseInt(fieldvalue);
            }
        });

        if (totalincome == 0) {
            $('#incomeError').dialog('open');
            validEmployment = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a server-side thing; OP should show the rendered code on the client, not on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it did not make any difference, it's ASP.NET so the variable gets parsed on the server before being sent to the page, I am baffled.